# App works on phone during debugging, does not work when apk is installed

Tags: android, gps, ksoap, fusedlocationproviderapi

I have made an app that uses GPS, Internet, FusedAPI and KSOAP. When I debug the app on my mobile using android studio, the app works fine. However when I create apk (signed), the activity that deals with Google Map, Fused API and GPS, does not work. All I can see is the screen flickering and the app returns to the activity before it.

Can anyone tell me what could possible be wrong.

build.gradle (Module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "online.hannuveda.transafe_rx"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies .jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
    compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.6.0@aar'
}
```

build.gradle (Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: show us your build.gradle, proguard settings and the Activity that is not working on signed apk

Comment: there are 2 build.gradle, one for Module and one for project. Which one do you need ?

Comment: maybe a proguard related problem?

Comment: one more question, I have added dependencies etc to build.gradle (Module) and not to the other one (which I guess is used while creating apk). Should I put all those dependencies there also ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the google-play-services dependency (`'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'`), you should declare your application of type MultidexApplication.

At the moment, you have just added `multiDexEnabled true` to the app level build.gradle file, which is not enough for a multidex configuration. You should also make changes in your Manifest and dependencies as well. Anyway, the instructions are the following :

1- Add the multidex dependency to your app level `build.gradle` :

```
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

2- Enable the multidex in your defaultConfigs in the app level build.gradle :

```
android {

defaultConfig {
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
   }
...
}
```

3- Define a new class MyApplication which extends MultidexApplication, which will serve as the entry point of your application.

```
public class MyApplication extends MultidexApplication
```

4- Finally, you should declare this new class in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="your.package.name">

<application
    android:name=".path-to.MyApplication">
    ...
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Nothing needs to be added to "MyApplication", just a blank class ?

Comment: just override the onCreate() method. that's it.

Comment: Hi, it still does not work. Can we do a chat to help resolve my issue ?